# How to use complex number to plot an Argand Diagram?

Tags: ios, objective-c, plot, complex-numbers

I like to create an [Argand Diagram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArgandDiagram.html) from a set of complex number by using Objective-C.

Are there any solution or template that are available that can help me to do this?

Can anyone recommend an approach?

Similar youtube link is provided but it's an android program: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0oTeZ12_ig

```
- (void)ComputeABCD
{
    double designFrequency = 1e9;
    double simulateFrequency = 1.5e9;
    double pi = 3.14159265359;
    double omega = 2*pi*simulateFrequency;

    double thetarad=1;

    complex double cascadedA=1+0*I;
    complex double cascadedB=0+0*I;
    complex double cascadedC=0+0*I;
    complex double cascadedD=1+0*I;

    complex double  A=0+0*I;
    complex double  B=0+0*I;
    complex double  C=0+0*I;
    complex double  D=0+0*I;

    complex double  newA=0+0*I;
    complex double  newB=0+0*I;
    complex double  newC=0+0*I;
    complex double  newD=0+0*I;

    int index=0;

    for (id element in storeImpedance)
    {
        id element2 = [storeLength objectAtIndex:index];
        id element3 = [storeIndex objectAtIndex:index];

        NSNumber *numberImpedance = (NSNumber *)element;
        double valueImpedance = [numberImpedance doubleValue];

        NSNumber *numberLength = (NSNumber *)element2;
        double valueLength = [numberLength doubleValue];

        NSNumber *numberIndex = (NSNumber *)element3;
        NSInteger valueIndex = [numberIndex integerValue];

        ++index;

        if (valueIndex==0)
        {
            thetarad=valueLength*pi/180*simulateFrequency/designFrequency;
            A=cos(thetarad);
            B=I*valueImpedance*sin(thetarad);
            C=I*sin(thetarad)/valueImpedance;
            D=cos(thetarad);
        }

        if (valueIndex==1)
        {
            thetarad=valueLength*pi/180*simulateFrequency/designFrequency;
            A=1;
            B=0;
            C=(I*tan(thetarad))/valueImpedance;
            D=1;

        }
        newA=cascadedA*A+cascadedB*C;
        newB=cascadedA*B+cascadedB*D;
        newC=cascadedC*A+cascadedD*C;
        newD=cascadedC*B+cascadedD*D;

        cascadedA=newA;
        cascadedB=newB;
        cascadedC=newC;
        cascadedD=newD;
    }

    printf("The MAT ABCD is:\n");
    printf("%g + %gi\n", creal(cascadedA), cimag(cascadedA));
    printf("%g + %gi\n", creal(cascadedB), cimag(cascadedB));
    printf("%g + %gi\n", creal(cascadedC), cimag(cascadedC));
    printf("%g + %gi\n", creal(cascadedD), cimag(cascadedD));
}
```

Comment: What's is your current issue? Translating the code? Understanding the maths behind it? What have you tried? If you just want to place points on a diagram, it's quite easy. Take: "a+bi as it was (x,b) point", if you have the e|z|theta, then translate it into a+bi, and you could to it too.

Comment: I'm unable sure how to start with the plotting a graph chart and how my result display plot the line. Can't find any sample code or template

Comment: First, understand your plotting graph chart library. Then, comeback with a narrowed question, because it's too broad.

Comment: I have look for complex number graph chart library but there is no available for complex number (argand diagram) available. Do u know any can recommend ?

Comment: Look for a "classic" graph chart library. A graph is just a representation, you could always translate your complex number into "graphic".

Comment: I have look at the all the chart. I think line chart with x and y is something similar but only the start point is not at the centre. What can I do?